# how to use UIImagePickerController (base on cocos2d 1.00rc)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to cocos2d. I use this [sample code](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5734), but the screen just displays a blue Nav bar.

**Anyone can tell me how to use the UIImagePickerController?**

Thanks.

Comment: The screen displays nothing but a blue navigation bar on top.obviously,the uiimagepickercontroller did not work as the sample code show.